# How do I match two columns and merge pandas dataframes on Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to match two columns (ie: values from Col1 and Col2 from Df1 match with ColA and Col2 from Df2) and do a merge on that. I'm having trouble with the merge syntax, I currently have `merged_df = df1.merge(df2,how='inner',left_on=['Col1,Col2'],right_on=['ColA,Col2])` 
but it doesn't seem to be working (it's giving me less than what I'm expecting). Any tips?

[image]

Comment: Try this syntax : `df1.merge(df2,how='inner',left_on=['Col1','Col2'], right_on=['ColA','Col2'])`

Comment: You're missing a few single quotes in your statement above.   This should return six records.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you tried, it returns the correct results:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='inner',left_on=['Col1','Col2'], right_on=['ColA','Col2'])
```

[image: merged_df]

It's an inner join (keeping only the matches) between both datasets, based on the available couples of `['Col1','Col2']` and `['ColA','Col2']`.
The matches are on rows 1 to 6 (or 0 to 5) in both datasets.